# How to drag and drop files to copy into directory?

Tags: java, file, file-io, drag-and-drop, awt

I have this label:

```
//---- label5 ----
label5.setText("Drag and drop your texture\npack in the box *.zip files");
label5.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
    "E:\\Chituri\\MBMLauncherJava\\src\\resursele\\dasdasdasd.png"));
```

But I want to make something like this:

```
//---- label5 ----
label5.setText("Drag and drop your texture\npack in the box *.zip files");
label5.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
    "E:\\Chituri\\MBMLauncherJava\\src\\resursele\\dasdasdasd.png"));
// drag files in the label > 
// automatically move files in particular folder (E:\\Chituri)
```

How I can do this?

i try this...

```
label5.setTransferHandler(transfer);
label5.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                    JLabel texturidrag = (JLabel)e.getSource();
                    TransferHandler handle = texturidrag.getTransferHandler();
                    handle.exportAsDrag(texturidrag, e, TransferHandler.COPY);
                }
            });
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) I mean *besides* asking random strangers on the internet to do it for you. Have you gone through the [D'n'D tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html) & the [basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) tutorial?  What is your actual, specific, question?  Where are you stuck?  Not your down voter (yet) but please show some effort.

Answer (score 1):

Try to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204580/swing-application-drag-drop-to-the-desktop-folder) post, especially answer and implement method `processFiles` to filter input files and handle just images, if you found image just create `ImageIcon` as you want.