# Is there any method in DragSourceAdapter.java Class that gives the drop location?

Tags: java, drag-and-drop

Is there any way to identify the drop location using `DragSourceAdapter.java`. I am trying to drag a image or file from the `JTable` to Desktop or any other location in native file system.

For this I have written a class which extends `DragSourceAdapter`-

public class FileDragGestureListener extends DragSourceAdapter implements DragGestureListener {

@Override
    public void dragGestureRecognized(DragGestureEvent dge) {
    }

```
 @Override
public void dragEnter(DragSourceDragEvent dsde) {
    DragSourceContext dragSourceContext = dsde.getDragSourceContext();
    dragSourceContext.setCursor(cursor);

}

@Override
public void dragExit(DragSourceEvent dse) {
    DragSourceContext dragSourceContext = dse.getDragSourceContext();
    dragSourceContext.setCursor(DragSource.DefaultCopyNoDrop);
}

public void dragDropEnd(DragSourceDropEvent dsde){
   Point point = dsde.getLocation();
}
```

}

In `dragDropEnd` method, the `DragSourceDropEvent` has `getLocation()` but how to get the exact path where the file or image has been dropped at native file system.

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204580/swing-application-drag-drop-to-the-desktop-folder

Comment: @user2389335 Thanks but still the same issue. How can I get the drop location? Imagine, I have dragged a file and dropped that file into `C:\abc` folder. So I need to identify that `C:\abc` location.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to identify the drop location?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942409/how-to-identify-the-drop-location)