# How to identify the drop location?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, awt

Sample program-

In a sample program I have a `JTable` that shows list of files. When I dragged that file and dropped it to any where in native file system, my program moves that file to the dropped location.

Behind the scene for sample program I have created a temporary file with the same name into the system's `temp` location and write the content into that temporary file of the originally dragged file. Once it done, the temporary file automatically gets move to the dropped location.

To run the sample program, please create a `txt` file `abc` insert some text and copy that file into the current working directory.

Here is the code-

```
package com.main;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author admin
 */
public class DragAndDropJavaApplicationMainClass {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        JavaApplicationPanel applicationPanel = new JavaApplicationPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(applicationPanel);
        Dimension dim = new Dimension(450, 225);
        frame.setPreferredSize(dim);
        frame.setMinimumSize(dim);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

FileDragGestureListener.java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.main;

import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.dnd.DragGestureEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DragGestureListener;
import java.awt.dnd.DragSource;
import java.awt.dnd.DragSourceAdapter;
import java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext;
import java.awt.dnd.DragSourceDragEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DragSourceEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

/**
 *
 * @author admin
 */
public class FileDragGestureListener extends DragSourceAdapter implements DragGestureListener {

    Cursor cursor;
    String txt = "temp";

    @Override
    public void dragGestureRecognized(DragGestureEvent dge) {
        try {
            File proxy_temp = File.createTempFile("tempdir", ".dir", null);
            File temp = new File(proxy_temp.getParent(), "abc.txt");
            File file = new File("abc.txt");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
            PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(temp);
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String s = sc.nextLine();
                printer.write(s);
            }
            printer.flush();
            printer.close();
            FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
            Icon icn = fsv.getSystemIcon(temp);
            Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            Dimension dim = tk.getBestCursorSize(icn.getIconWidth(), icn.getIconHeight());
            BufferedImage buff = new BufferedImage(dim.width, dim.height,
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            if (DragSource.isDragImageSupported()) {
                dge.startDrag(DragSource.DefaultCopyDrop, buff, new Point(0, 0),
                        new TextFileTransferable(temp),
                        this);
            } else {
                cursor = tk.createCustomCursor(buff, new Point(0, 0), "sString");
                dge.startDrag(cursor, null, new Point(0, 0),
                        new TextFileTransferable(temp),
                        this);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void dragEnter(DragSourceDragEvent dsde) {
        DragSourceContext dragSourceContext = dsde.getDragSourceContext();
        dragSourceContext.setCursor(cursor);

    }

    @Override
    public void dragExit(DragSourceEvent dse) {
        DragSourceContext dragSourceContext = dse.getDragSourceContext();
        dragSourceContext.setCursor(DragSource.DefaultCopyNoDrop);
    }
}
```

JavaApplicationPanel.java

```
 package com.main;

import java.awt.dnd.DnDConstants;
import java.awt.dnd.DragGestureRecognizer;
import java.awt.dnd.DragSource;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author admin
 */
public class JavaApplicationPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form JavaApplicationPanel
     */
    public JavaApplicationPanel() {
        initComponents();
        DragSource ds = DragSource.getDefaultDragSource();
        DragGestureRecognizer dgr = ds.createDefaultDragGestureRecognizer(jTable,
                DnDConstants.ACTION_MOVE, new FileDragGestureListener());
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable = new javax.swing.JTable();

        jTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {"abc.txt", "1 KB", "Tuesday, ‎January ‎29, ‎2013, ‏‎12:09:24 PM", ""}
            },
            new String [] {
                "File Name", "Size", "Last Modified", "Download Location"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class
            };
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, false, false, false
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 632, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 272, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    public javax.swing.JTable jTable;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

TextFileTransferable.java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.main;

import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author admin
 */
public class TextFileTransferable implements Transferable {

    File temp;

    public TextFileTransferable(File temp) throws IOException {

        this.temp = temp;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) {
        List list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(temp);
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {

        DataFlavor[] df = new DataFlavor[1];
        df[0] = DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor;
        return df;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {

        if (flavor == DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The only issue in my sample program is that I need to know the location where that temporary file has been moved finally from the system's `temp` location to the actual dropped location. i.e where the user has actual dropped that file at native file system.

Comment: theoretically, you need to register a WatchService which notifies about changes to the native file system. Practically, that's a bit useless if you can't narrow the probable target location - you need a watcher on _every_ folder ...